# App.get not being triggered when expected

Tags: node.js, express

When I load the page, the console logs nothing when it's like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('public', {
 extensions: ['html']
}));

const YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:4242';

app.get('/', async(req, res)=> {
 console.log('a')
 res.send('a')
})

app.listen(4242, () => console.log('Running on port 4242'));
```

However, when changed to something arbitrary (i.e. app.get('/a',...)) and then accessed it works as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

when you go to http://localhost:4242 url then you can see a response and console log like this.
[image]

Comment: This isn't the full code, I have a bunch of html pages. app.get works whenever there is no html page for the url I'm accessing. I'm trying to figure out why,